# Component is required yet it throws error

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I simply don't understand what's the matter. It throws me that error

```
Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Anonymous] Using Ext.Msg without requiring Ext.MessageBox
```

And this is my code

```
function ShowPasswordPrompt(callbackFunction)
{
    Ext.require('Ext.MessageBox');

    var x = Ext.Msg.prompt(
        'Restricted Area!',

        ...
```

Comment: Have you set your loader to load your Ext. package to your touch path ? It looks like `Ext.Loader.setPath({'Ext' : 'touch/src'});`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the Ext.MessageBox dependency of your code : http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-cfg-requires

You are telling sencha that you need this class to be loaded before running your app. Then your JS code can reference this class.

code :

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'MyApp',
    requires : [
        'Ext.MessageBox',
    ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did that before and unfortunatelly it did not help.